# mvc3 Elmah user identity name issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, identity, elmah

I am using Elmah for MVC and have secured it successfully but the issue i am having is that it won't show the log for the authorized user for instance this is my web.config for Elmah

```
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="35" />
```

users login and then they're **user.identity.name** is a numerical number based on that how can I make user #35 have access to elmah? since **i don't use roles** in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just solved it, in case anyone wants to use user.identity.name and allow for a specific user all you have to do is add

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="35" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using roles, if you wanted to secure the elmah.axd endpoint to a specific user you could use the `<location>` element:

```
<location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
       <authorization>   
         <allow users="some_username" />
         <deny users="*" />
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Now `some_username` will be the only user that will have access to the `/elmah.axd` endpoint.